# Help with inheritance hierarchy design

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm having trouble designing an inheritance hierarchy.

In the figure:

**Base class:**

- This uses the Template Method.
- Contains core logic/algorithm that
  calls virtual/abstract methods

**Derived types:**

- These classes provides concrete implementation of the virtual/abstract methods expected by the Base.

**Conditions:**

1. I have a virtual method (Run).
2. The default Run method uses another virtual method (Proc).
3. If a derived class uses the default Run behaviour, they must implement Proc.
4. If a derived class overrides the Run behaviour, then it shouldn't have to care about the existence of Proc, let alone overriding it.

[image]

I've considered making Run() abstract and let each derived class handle their own.
But then I'll end up with duplicate code.

[image]

I'm using a simplified example here.

In my actual project, I have several "Run"-typed virtual methods, each calling several "Proc"-typed methods.

Because of that, I have a whole bunch of virtual "Proc" methods with "throw new NotImplementedException()"

Creating a new derived type is also confusing, because the coder may not know which virtual methods must be implemented/can be ignored/etc.

I've considered using a strategy pattern, but since I have several "Run" methods, each one of those would have to be a strategy, which seems like overkill/overengineering.

[image]

Is there any way to simplify this?

---

**[Update 1]**

Here's an example that's closer to the kind of methods I'm working with

[image]

And imagine yet another method:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered creating a default implementation in the top-level class, letting your descendant classes call Proc in the Top-level class, and only overriding Proc if necessary?

Comment: This sounds like the perfect example for a strategy pattern.  You could also have type 2 and type 3 inherit from a type 5 that inherits from Base.  This would be the standard inheritance way, but I would stick with strategy.  If you later add classes that share run then they can reuse different run methods.  Especially if you already have an example of two types sharing a run method.

Comment: "each one of those would have to be a strategy, which seems like overkill/overengineering." I disagree. I think it is perfectly fine to express this behavior in it's own class.

Comment: In the update, what corresponds to `proc()` in the new diagram?  `getData()`?

Comment: GetData  corresponds to Run,  GetSelectionName and GetXmlList to proc.  Next example,  RunQuery(Run),  InsertData(proc).

Comment: It looks to me as if the different getData() implementations return different types...

Comment: GetData is an example of different implementation across subclasses.  Eg, one need to parse xml to recreate the data object,  while another uses the Binary formatter,  and a third simply holds and restores from memory.

Comment: But they are returning the same basic class of object?  Would hope so, but it's not clear from the diagram, which shows the way the data is retrieved rather than what it actually is.

Comment: Yup, you can just assume so. The 2 examples I've added in the update is to show how it's unfeasible to use inheritance (single parent) for my scenarios. It's starting to seem like I really need to use a strategy pattern here. That way, 1) my Base class will not need those empty NotImplemented methods, 2) I can share common code in a strategy, and 3) I can enforce abstract methods/interface within the strategy class. I'm just a bit hesitant, because I'll have to do this for every method in Base that behaves this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created your own, unnecessary problem here.

1. Everything must be **runnable**
2. The default implementation of **run** requires **proc**
3. Anybody implementing their own **run** can ignore **proc** (but all that useless code still adorns the class and any descendants).
4. Your concrete, exception-throwing implementation of **proc** *enables* people to set up themselves up for runtime errors.  Why do that?

OK, so you wanted to be helpful by providing a default implementation but you have bolted on implementation details which you *know* will not always be desired.  You say you want to avoid code duplication but you have encumbered your hierarchy with code which will be obsolete as soon as somebody extends it.

I would strongly urge you to go the interface/abstract-base-class route here:

1. Abstract base class **runnable**
2. Abstract base class **proccer**
3. Create proc-calling concrete implementation of **runnable**.
4. Wherever possible (even in **proc-caller** class methods) refer to **runnables** and not **proc-callers**).

So your default **run** implentation can be used where desired but can be dropped without penalty.  Also, this way people are forced to implement **proc** if they mix in **proc-caller** but you don't have to write that "Not implemented" version of **proc** - they can't compile their code if they do not implement **proc**.  Why create that runtime trap when you can require them to fix things at compile time?

If you think there are other useful behaviours which should be available, you can avoid code duplication by providing "interfaces" in the same way I have shown for **proc**.  Anybody who wants that can mix it in.

Comment: did you mean something like in the 3rd figure (strategy approach)?

Answer (score 3):

Why not add one more level into your hierarchy?

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Run()
    {
        // some code
    }
}

public class ProcBase : Base
{
    public sealed override void Run() // make sure it cannot be overriden
    {
        Proc();
        base.Run();
    }

    public virtual void Proc()
    { 
        // some code
    }
}

public class Type1 : Base // same with Type4
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        base.Run();
    }
}

public class Type2 : ProcBase // same with Type3
{
    public override void Proc()
    {
        base.Proc();
    }
}
```

Also, if this hierarchy changes between different `Runs`, then using strategy pattern becomes inevitable.

Comment: Perhaps `Proc()` could be made protected?

Comment: @Euphoric the hierarchy _does_ indeed change (I've updated my question). I have several methods *like* Run(), and it would be hard, if not impossible, to refactor and group multiple base classes

Comment: @jsjslim Then I see no other way than to use Strategy for each different Run.